# Extract coefficients from polynomial with specific form

Tags: polynomials, coefficients

I have following polynomial:
$$ f(x,t)=a_0(x)(x-t)^0+a_1(x)(x-t)+a_2(x) (x-t)^2+...+\frac{a_{n-1}(x)}{(n-1)!}(x-t)^{n-1}$$
Can I extract that $\frac{a_{n-1}(x)}{(n-1)!}$ coefficients?

```
Coefficient[f[x,t],x-t]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Might check `Series` for this. (I'd try it myself, but no input code was provided.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[x_, t_] = Sum[Subscript[a, i][x] (x - t)^i, {i, 0, 6}];
```

> $a_6(x) (x-t)^6+a_5(x) (x-t)^5+a_4(x) (x-t)^4+a_3(x) (x-t)^3+a_2(x) (x-t)^2+a_1(x) (x-t)+a_0(x)$

```
CoefficientList[f[x, x - t], t]
```

> $\left\{a_0[x],a_1[x],a_2[x],a_3[x],a_4[x],a_5[x],a_6[x]\right\}$

Comment: You're genius, thank you very much!